# Can I get my Google Calendar shown in my iCloud Calendar on my PC?

Tags: icloud, iphone, windows, ipad, google-calendar

It works great on my iPad and iPhone, and I would like to be able to see both the iCloud Calendar and my Google Calendar at one page on my PC (Win 7).

Answer (score 1):

You need to "subscribe" to the iCloud calendar from your Google calendar.

In iCloud:

1. Click the Share button to the right of the calendar you want to share, then select Public Calendar.
2. Click Email Link.
3. Type *your* Gmail addresses in the To field, then click Send.

   [image]

In Google:

1. Copy and paste the link from the email you receive into Google’s “Add by URL” field in the “Other Calendars” section.
2. It can and most often WILL take up to 24 hours for events from the subscribed calendar to display in Google.

   [image]

Comment: This does not work for me because it won't sync going forward.  I get all the events immediately at first, but that's all... no new events or changes made on the iCloud calendar will reflect on the Google calendar, not even a day later.

Answer (score 0):

The web interface for iCloud only shows iCloud calendars. As far as I can tell it can't display Google calendars, as the Calendar apps can. If you want to see both iCloud and Google calendars on the same web page, then I must ask, why do you need two different calendar services? I personally only use Google calendars, which the Calendar apps on my Mac, iPad and iPhone are perfectly capable of using (with Siri!) without iCloud. You could also choose to use only iCloud calendars, for the same effect, the only difference being which web app you use when you're on your PC.

If you insist on using both services, though, [these](http://computing.physics.harvard.edu/icloud) instructions could probably be used to configure the Google calendar web app to display iCloud calendar info through iCloud's CalDAV interface.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had hoped for a solution. My reason is: I am using Google Calendar and my husbond is using iCloud (synced with his Outlook) and shared with me. It would be nice to be able to view both our calendars at the same time on my PC. As noted it is possible on iPhone and iPad, so I have to go on checking the calendars there.

Comment: Why not just use the calendar app on the PC, add both accounts and use that?